# Поиск содержимого документа в бакете Couchbase (golang gocb lib)

Tags: json, http, golang, rest, search

Есть следующая структура:

```golang
type Inventory struct {
    Ip     string            `json:"ip,omitempty"`
    Tag    []string          `json:"tag,omitempty"`
    Apps   []string          `json:"apps,omitempty"`
    Active bool              `json:"active,omitempty"`
    Params map[string]string `json:"params,omitempty"`
}
```

В бакете **couchbase** лежат документы с данными внутри согласно этой структуре.

Необходимо реализовать поиск (скорее всего **полнотекстовый**, другие способы не давали и близко нужного результата) по содержимому всех документов в бакете и в результате вывести документы, соответствующие запросу.

Пример запроса:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8059/search -d '{"ip":"1.2.3.4", "tag":["foo","bar"], "active":true, "params":{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}}'
```

*необходимо получить документы, в которых есть все данные, указанные в запросе.*

Проблема в том, что исходя из запроса необходимо искать данные в определенном поле документа в соответствии с запросом и я не совсем могу понять как это реализовать, т.к. в структуре разные типы данных (`map`, `string`, `array`, `bool`).

Использую пакет **gocb** для работы с **API Couchbase**: [github.com/couchbase/gocb](https://github.com/couchbase/gocb)

Буду рад любой помощи!

Небольшой пример имеющегося кода:

```golang
func search(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

var search Inventory

type FtsHit struct {
    ID string `json:"id,omitempty"`
}

body, error := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(error.Error()) //TODO: обработка ошибки
}

error = json.Unmarshal(body, &search)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(w, "can't unmarshal: ", error.Error()) //TODO: обработка ошибки
}

//TODO: составной запрос (работает только в случае указания значений для всех полей)
qp := cbft.NewConjunctionQuery(
    cbft.NewPhraseQuery(search.Ip).Field("ip"),
    cbft.NewPhraseQuery(search.Tag[0]).Field("tag"),
    cbft.NewPhraseQuery(search.Apps[0]).Field("apps"),
    cbft.NewBooleanFieldQuery(search.Active).Field("active"),
    cbft.NewQueryStringQuery(search.Params).Field("params"),
)

q := gocb.NewSearchQuery("search-index", qp)

rows, err := bucket.ExecuteSearchQuery(q)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

var result Inventory

for _, hit := range rows.Hits() {
    res, _ := bucket.Get(hit.Id, &result)
    fmt.Printf(hit.Id, ":", res)
}

jsonDocument, error := json.Marshal(&result)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println(error.Error())
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v\n", string(jsonDocument))
```

Проблема в том, что практически все методы фулл текста принимают только `string`. Конечно, в теории, можно все привести к строкам, но есть еще один нюанс: составной запрос не работает в случае если хотя бы один параметр пропущен (ip, tag, apps и т.д.). Собственно вопрос в том, как сделать данную функцию правильно, эффективно и "красиво".

P.S. *функция должна быть универсальна, т.е. работать вне зависимости от кол-ва запрашиваемых полей в запросе.*

Comment: Добавьте код, даже применый того что вы хотите. Я немного запутался в вашем вопросе.

Comment: @biosckon , добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пояснения в коментариях. Формы запросов я пытался использовать ваши.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/couchbase/gocb/cbft"
)

func main() {

    for _, j := range [][]byte{json1, json2, json3} {

        // первое загоняем запрос в карту вместо структуры
        search := make(map[string]interface{})

        err := json.Unmarshal(j, &search)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        // теперь у нас в карте только те поля что имеются в запросе

        // временный слайс для хранения индивидуальных запросов
        qa := []cbft.FtsQuery{}

        for key, val := range search {

            // смотрим на тип поля запроса
            switch valt := val.(type) {

            case string: // попадётся Ip
                qa = append(qa, cbft.NewPhraseQuery(valt).Field(key))

            case []interface{}: // попадётся Tag Apps
                // Здесь я не уверен что вам именно нужно
                // тупо перебираем все елементы слайса и добаляем все.
                // Можете добавить только первый как в вашем коде.
                for _, item := range valt {
                    if s, ok := item.(string); ok {
                        qa = append(qa, cbft.NewPhraseQuery(s).Field(key))
                    }
                }

            case bool: // Active
                qa = append(qa, cbft.NewBooleanFieldQuery(valt).Field(key))

            case map[string]interface{}: // Params
                // Здесь я тоже не в полне понимаю что именно вы хотите делать
                // Можно по аналогии с []interface{}
                for _, item := range valt { // _ пропускаем key
                    if s, ok := item.(string); ok {
                        // NewQueryStringQuery(search.Params).Field("params") не работает
                        // Оставняю решение вам :)
                        qa = append(qa, cbft.NewPhraseQuery(s).Field(key))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // qa... разпаковываем слайс
        qp := cbft.NewConjunctionQuery(qa...)

        // отправляете запрос и открываете пиво
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", qp)

    }

}

var (
    json1 = []byte(`{
  "ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "tag": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ],
  "active": true,
  "params": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}`)

    json2 = []byte(`{
  "ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "active": true
}`)

    json3 = []byte(`{
  "params": {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
  }
}`)
)
```

Выхлоп таков

```golang
&{{map[conjuncts:[0xc42000c030 0xc42000c038 0xc42000c040 0xc42000c048 0xc42000c050 0xc42000c058]]}}
&{{map[conjuncts:[0xc42000c078 0xc42000c080]]}}
&{{map[conjuncts:[0xc42000c098 0xc42000c0a0]]}}
```

Т.е. теперь ваш составной запрос будет в точности как указано в json запросе.

PS: На реальной базе не тестировал. Но вроде должно работать....

Comment: Была идея с картой, но думал, что возможно обойтись без нее :) Спасибо!